# Google map API is not displaying my map even though I have the correct authentication key

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-2

Google API map not displaying when I load my code in a google chrome browser. I created my authentication key with in a new project on the Google Cloud Platform.

I've tried generating a new authentication key on the Google Cloud platform by creating a new project, but that did not seemed to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <style>
  #map{
     height:100%;
  }
  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="output">Complete JavaScript Course </div>
<div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
 key=<<my key>>"></script>
 <script src="app.js">

  window.onload = init;
      var m = document.getElementById('map');

      function init() {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(placeMap);
      }

      function placeMap(data) {
          var options = {
              center: {
                  lat: data.coords.latitude
                  , lng: data.coords.longitude
              }
              , zoom: 5
          }
          var map = new google.maps.Map(m, options);
          console.dir(data);
      }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As I've already stated, the google map api will not display a map of my actual location.

Comment: The api is probably not ready yet, instead of window.load have you tried using the callback they provide?

Comment: what do you mean and when should it be ready?

Comment: Basically the google api you are using, accept another parameter alongside with the apiKey that is a callback , which will be called when the api is ready to be used , more information here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API

Comment: Are you **really** using the deprecated and turned off v2 version of the API (as your tag implies)? Synchronously loading the v3 (and the deprecated and turned off v2 api) works.  You  _can_ load it asynchronously if you want (most of their examples do that).

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues with the posted code.

1. Your map div doesn't have a size, you need to define the size of `html` and `body` so the `#map` 100% height has something to reference:

```
<style>
#map{
   height:100%;
}
</style>
```

should be:

```
<style>
html, body, #map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

2. you have an unneeded `src` on your script tag:

```
<script src="app.js">
```

should be:

```
<script>
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wcqjhpfo/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">Complete JavaScript Course </div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script>
  window.onload = init;
  var m = document.getElementById('map');

  function init() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(placeMap);
  }

  function placeMap(data) {
    var options = {
      center: {
        lat: data.coords.latitude,
        lng: data.coords.longitude
      },
      zoom: 5
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(m, options);
    console.dir(data);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Well spotted, @geocodezip. Spent hours trying to find what made my old webpage show a Google Map while my new one didn't. I'd switched from #map to .map in the CSS and hadn't put an id on the map div. Neither had I explicitly dimensioned the height of the map div as it was a grid area and I assumed a height: auto; would do . . .

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the API using the callback after google maps have already been loaded. This is done by passing in a parameter to google maps initialization by passing in `callback` as a query parameter. You also need to activate your api to have Javascript functionality[image: Javascript API]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap(position) {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: position,
          zoom: 8
        });
      }

      function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            initMap({
              lng: position.coords.longitude, lat: position.coords.latitude});
          });
        } else {
          initMap({lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644});
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCD9OuD6hAbRm5JNSEpkCTE6HzhaOp5uCc&callback=getLocation"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```